# Ionic Cap Websocket connection refused during Handshake in Android Webview

Tags: websocket, android-webview, handshake, solana-web3js, ionic-react

I'm making a **hybrid app** working with Ionic React, using **solana web3.js** module.
Everything works fine when I launch web server, and access on computer and mobile (chrome, firefox).

To build on android, I pass a custom function to fetch when i start the connection on Solana to deal with CORS policy natively.
But there is also **websocket** pubsub on web3.js module, that subscribes everytime it checks a transaction (for example requestAirdrop function).

So, the error I get in Android Studio logcat is : *Msg: WebSocket connection to 'wss://api.devnet.solana.com/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 403*

DYORing during many hours, what i ended with is :

- add something to capacitor webview options that will make the connection accepted by the server/validator ?
- change websocket module inside the solana web3.js node module, allowing the pubsub to work natively ?

Second option will be a nightmare, and don't think I have the knowledge to do it well.

If you see other options, don't hesitate!

**UPDATE** *The issue doesn't come from the webview as a connection from the native app to a web server (specifying server.url to that server in capacitor config) works perfectly with websocket. So the issue is part of capacitor hosting on Android.*

and here is my config :

ionic react :

"@awesome-cordova-plugins/core": "^5.44.0",
"@awesome-cordova-plugins/http": "^5.44.0",
"@capacitor/android": "4.0.1",
"@capacitor/app": "4.0.1",
"@capacitor/core": "4.0.1",
"@ionic/cli": "^6.20.1",
"@ionic/react": "6.2.1",
"@ionic/react-router": "6.2.1",
"@solana/web3.js": "1.53.0",
"cordova-plugin-advanced-http": "^3.3.1",

and other that I think irrelevant

android :

Android Studio Chipmunk 2021. Patch2
Runtime version : 11.0.12
Emulator: Pixel2 Android 11.0

I work on Debian.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Perhaps try [capacitor-community/http](https://github.com/capacitor-community/http) instead of  `@awesome-cordova-plugins/http`?  Also, Ionic is [readying the release of a Capacitor 4 http solution](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/5145).

Comment: I don't have any pb with the http cordova plugin, i can fetch. My issue is about websocket subscribes when using the webview locally